# How to plant the bean sprout efficiently?

Tags: sprouting

I am thinking of raising the bean sprout myself but do not how where to start.

I did a search on Google and the easiest way is to use a plastic bottle and then raise the seed inside. After 3 days, cut the bottleneck and get the bean sprouts. However, this way of doing things really wastes the bottle.

I am wondering if you could please share your simple way to make the bean sprout.

P/S: I also think of buying the bean sprout maker but it seems not to be really available in New Zealand, and the price is quite high to me.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but the sprout makers are available. A few companies are selling this one.

[image]

Note, I am not associated with the manufacturer or sellers.